# Regex for U.S. Currency (without ,) for amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a requirement on Regex like below for U.S. Currency (without ,).

If the user enter amount in TextBox control then it should Auto format with below expected format.

If value is **1111** - then Auto format with **$ 1111.00**

If value is **$1111** - then Auto format with **$ 1111.00**

If value is **$ 1111** - then Auto format with **$ 1111.00**

If value is **1111.0** - then Auto format with **$ 1111.00**

If value is **$1111.00** - then Auto format with **$ 1111.00**

I tried like below and it is not working.

```
\$?\s?(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)
```

**Format**: **$ $1**

Any suggestion please.

Comment: What is the language? Note that pattern-matching tag should not be used when you actually mean regular expressions.

Comment: I am voting to close as duplicate, because regex isn't the best way to handle your currency formatting, q.v. the duplicate link.

Comment: I don't have a gold medal in JS, hence I can't close.  But I'd rather use decimal formatting built into JavaScript than a really complex regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, It is not duplicate.. please don't close. This requirement is for textbox. If the user enter amount '1111' then i should autoformat with '$ 1111.00'

Comment: This is not a regex problem.

Comment: @Soviut I killed my answer quickly as soon as the OP informed me of so many edge cases for which regex is not well suited.

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother with a regex since this isn't a string matching or searching problem. Instead, write a function that does the following instead:

- Strip all whitespace characters and `$` characters by replacing them with `''` nothing
- Split the resulting string on `.`
- Take your two tokens from the split and name them `dollars` and `cents`
- Take the `cents` value and pad it with 2 `0`s (there are dozens of string padding algorithms out there)
- Recombine the string with the currency symbol, a space, `dollars`, a decimal, and the padded `cents`
- Reapply it to the textbox value

Call this function each time the textbox changes.

**UPDATE:** If you're targeting the most recent browsers, you can take advantage of the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) library. It has facilities for handling internationalization and localization of strings, numbers, dates and currencies.

To decide if you can use the Intl library, check this support chart

http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization

Comment: No, don't write a function. Use a library, such as `Intl`.

Comment: @torazaburo feel free to write your own answer. I proposed a function because we don't know the scope of OP's problem. SO had a real problem with "just use JQuery" a few years back and I don't want to repeat that by making library/frameworks recommendations over solutions to the immediate problem.

Comment: Additionally, support for the Intl library is relatively recent especially in the mobile browser space. http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Looking at the support chart you kindly included, I'm wondering what kind of browser support requirements would motivate anyone **not** to use the lib.

Comment: @torazaburo it's only very recently (less than 1 year as of this post) supported on mobile which accounts for at least 50%+ of most site traffic these days. Having it crash on handhelds is a really bad user experience.

Comment: I don't see that from the support chart. What handheld is it going to crash on?

Comment: @torazaburo Anyone running Safari 9 on either iOS or desktop. Anyone with a 2 year old feature phone running Android, etc.